# Inject two services in third service angular 4

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-services

[please find image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtkyY.png)I have three services. UserService, storage service, cartservice.
I am trying to use functions of userservice and storage service in cartservice.
But I am unable to inject it in constructor. second parameter of service is always undefined.
code:
cart service-

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { UserService } from "./service";
import { StorageService } from "./storage.service";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { Observer } from "rxjs/Observer";

@Injectable()
export class CartService {

public constructor( private storageService: StorageService,
private _UserService: UserService) {
console.log('_UserService--' + _UserService);/* Always undefined. It will         work if I switch its position to first in constuctor. but then storageservice will be undefined*/
```

}
}

Comment: Please show any path or any concept I am unaware

Comment: no cant be, it should work

Comment: Try `setTimeout(() => console.log('_UserService--' + _UserService));`

Comment: It should work without this as well..

Comment: Thank you for replying  @R.RichardsBut this is the case. I am still getting undefined after trying ur solutions. I also checked in debugger

Comment: same undefined only. How can i post a image here? @trichetriche

Comment: I have added image in question which shows data in debugger @trichetriche

Comment: Is it undefined when you actually run the code, or just in your debugger?

Comment: on runtime only. Compile time I am not getting undefined or null reference in service methods. @Und3rTow

Comment: Is there any limit of number of services we can inject in a service? Because service at first position is working perfect. @Und3rTow

Answer (score 0):

Posting this so that someone may get help.
My issue was for this service there was explicit dependency declared in app.module.ts

```
providers: [
{
  deps: [StorageService],
  provide: CartService,
  useClass: CartService
}
]
```

this was the reason it was not taking second service.